# ¿Cómo acceder al resultado de una llamada al método artist.gettopalbums de last.fm?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

queria saber por favor como ejecutar este metodo de la api de Lastfm es sencillo pero no logro ejectuarlo correctamente.
Yo se que estoy accediendo mal a la etiqueta

mi intento de usar el metodo:

```js
$.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/',
        data : 'method=artist.gettopalbums&' +
               'artist=cooldplay&' +
               'api_key=57ee3318536b23ee81d6b27e36997cde&' +
               'format=json',
        dataType : 'jsonp',
        success : function(data) {
            $('#success #artistName').html(data.topalbums.artist.name);
           
        },
        error : function(code, message){
            $('#error').html('Error Code: ' + code + ', Error Message: ' + message);            
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="success">
    <div id="artistName"></div>
    <div id="artistImage"></div>
    <div id="artistBio"></div>
</div>
<div id="error"></div>
```

Cual seria la manera correcta de ejecutar el metodo .getTopAlbums ?

Comment: Hola Diego, en lugar de usar `jsfiddle` puedes dejar el códido directamente aquí`

Comment: Gracias Carlos no me habia dado cuenta que era un array, claro ahora con .each lo recorro todo.

Comment: Una duda me quedo cuando intento acceder a la etiqueta listeners (que es un entero), no me retorna nada, a esa etiqueta no la trata como un object?                                   data.topalbums.album[0].artist.listeners                                                no retorna nada

Comment: `artist` solo tiene las propiedades `mbid` que es un GUID, `name` que es nombre de artista y `url` con la URL del artista en last.fm no existe la propiedad `listeners`

Comment: la etiqueta html5 aca http://www.last.fm/api/show/artist.getTopAlbums abajo hay una etiqueta que se llama listeners y tiene un entero, no se puede acceder a ella?abajo de mbid esta dicha etiqueta

Comment: En la etiqueta que dice "sample response" ahi esta, no en params.

Comment: Es verdad que sale en el sample response pero he tratado con GET y POST en formato JSON y XML y ninguno me devuelve el campo listeners, la documentación no parece estar de acuerdo a los response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error que estoy obteniendo en la consola de Chrome es:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

Esto sucede porque `data.topalbums.artist` es `undefined` y la razón de esto es que `data.topalbums` devuelve un objeto que contiene un array llamado `album` y este recién contiene una lista a la cual podrías acceder al primer elemento para obtener el objeto deseado al que le puedes consultar el `artist.name`

```
data.topalbums.album[0].artist.name
```

El código completo a continuación:

```js
$.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/',
        data : 'method=artist.gettopalbums&' +
               'artist=cooldplay&' +
               'api_key=57ee3318536b23ee81d6b27e36997cde&' +
               'format=json',
        dataType : 'jsonp',
        success : function(data) {
            $('#success #artistName').html(data.topalbums.album[0].artist.name);
           
        },
        error : function(code, message){
            $('#error').html('Error Code: ' + code + ', Error Message: ' + message);            
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="success">
    <div id="artistName"></div>
    <div id="artistImage"></div>
    <div id="artistBio"></div>
</div>
<div id="error"></div>
```